# supportsInterface reverts without message when address does not implement ERC165

Tags: solidity, interfaces

In my transfer function, I want to only allow the `to` address to be a contract that implements a certain interface.

I used this to check:

```
require(IERC165(to).supportsInterface(0xabcdef), "Wrong interface");
```

This works correctly if `to` is a contract address that implements ERC165. But when `to` is an EOA or a contract that doesn't implements ERC165, the statement will revert without any revert message. It seems like `supportsInterface` might have been "undefined" and hence the error. I might not have done the check safely and correctly since `to` really can be any address.

How should I do a check for the interface in a safe and more graceful way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way is to `isContract` to detect EOA and then use try/catch for contracts

```
require(isContract(to), "Not a contract");

try IERC165(to).supportsInterface(0xabcdef) returns (bool supported) {
    // Contracts support ERC-165
    require(supported, "Unsupported interface");
} catch (bytes memory /*lowLevelData*/) {
    // Contracts doesn't support ERC-165
    require(supported, "Unsupported ERC-165");
}
```